# Function input is contract - How to interact

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm going through Maker's OTC contract and they have this:

```
function isTokenPairWhitelisted(
    ERC20 baseToken,
    ERC20 quoteToken
)
    public
    constant
    returns (bool)
{
    return (_menu[keccak256(baseToken, quoteToken)] || _menu[keccak256(quoteToken, baseToken)]);
}
```

I'm trying to interact with it in truffle, but this isn't working:

```
  test1 = await ERC20.new();
  test2 = await ERC20.new();
  await oasisDex.isTokenPairWhitelisted(test1,test2);
```

I get the 'Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function'.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Web3 v0.x: `await oasisDex.isTokenPairWhitelisted(test1.address,test2.address);`

Web3 v1.x: `await oasisDex.isTokenPairWhitelisted(test1._address,test2._address);`

Web3 v0.x is used in all Truffle versions up to v4.1.14, and possibly even later.

In addition, you might want to obtain the returned value (i.e., `var x = await ...`).

Comment: Thanks!  So it's just the address?  why do they have it specified as the whole contract?

Comment: To let you know that they expect this contract to be deployed at the addresses that you provide.